# Optimal way of checking if any of multiple strings are non-empty (in php)

Tags: php, string

I have several strings which may or may not be empty. If any of them are non-empty, a mysql insertion should be called.

I've coded it simply, but was thinking about the *fastest* method of testing if *ANY* of them is non-empty.

```
$a = something;
$b = something;
$c = something;
```

Options

1. if($a!="" || $b!="" || $c!="")
2. if($a.$b.$c!="")
3. if(strlen($a) || strlen($b) || strlen($c))
4. if(strlen($a)>0 || strlen($b)>0 || strlen($c)>0)
5. if(strlen($a.$b.$c))
6. if(strlen($a.$b.$c)>0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
if (!$a || !$b || !$c){
   ...
}
```

There is no overhead of a function like `strlen` etc. The `!` is good bet there.

Comment: why those `!`? He needs to `do stuff` if any of them is non-empty, rather than if any of them is empty.

Comment: @binaryLV: Ignore the `do stuff` part, it is upto OP what he wants to do based on that condition :)

Comment: Steve does not want to do anything, when `!$a || !$b || !$c` ;) According to his question, he "wants to do something", when `$a || $b || $c`

Comment: '0' or 0 will be considered as empty values, so make sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't one way of finding out be testing by generating, let's say, at set of 1000 random strings and traverse that set for each option? I assume it's quite a naive way and reading about the native code for each function would generate a more thorough answer, but still, it's easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the most relevant functions on your list, namely [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) and [isset](http://www.php.net/isset).

Comment: @winvds - is that faster than @Sarfraz 's approach?

Comment: Benchmark them, I think empty should be faster though, but it might not be what you're looking for (ie. '0' will also be considered as an empty value, whereas isset will consider it as a set value). Sarfrazs answer has the same problem though.

Comment: `empty()` and `isset()` are not functions, they are language constructs.

Comment: @binaryLV: Nope they are functions, the parenthesis are required, as opposed to `print` or `echo`, which actually are a language construct.

Comment: @wimvds, RTFM. It's written in manual of both `empty()` and `isset()` that "Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions". Try also `var_dump(function_exists('isset'))`, if you don't believe official documentation.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected - they should be more consistent in the docs though, but does this even matter for the problem at hand? :p

Comment: @wimvds, another way of checking - `function isset(){}` will generate "syntax error, unexpected T_ISSET, expecting T_STRING or '('" parse error instead of "Cannot redeclare isset()" fatal error.

Comment: This might matter, but it depends on how PHP is implemented. Calling functions might be more "expensive" than using language constructs.